# In Java, is there some kind of coding method that's better than excessive if..else statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

Currently, I have a large plot of Java code that works perfectly. In it, I have a ton of various if...else statements gathered. Is there a more efficient way of having the same logic as a lot if...else statements w/out having such a jumbled file? Perhaps w/ cases?

What I have currently is something along these lines:

```
int input = (some numeric value);
if (input == 0) { ... } else { ... }
if (input == 1) { ... } else { ... }
/* And so on and so forth */
```

Comment: Switch statements. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kon! Helped a lot! I'm recently coming off of a C binge so this was a great reminder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! This looks like a great time to use the `switch` [statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) -

```
switch (input) {
  case 0: /* do something */ break;
  case 1: /* do something else */ break;
  default: /* do a third something */ break;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, when ever I have a conditional that is a `if ((some numeric value) && (some other numeric value)) { ... }` and replace it w/ `switch((some numeric value) { case 0: { if((some other numeric value)) { ... } } })`, I don't get the same logical output as I did w/ the if conditional. Can something like the if statement I used be used w/ cases?

Comment: Yes, but in your example here the `some other numeric value` must be 0 (since that's the switch condition).

Answer (score 2):

```
switch(someVar) {
    case someConstant:
        //code
        break;
    case someOtherConstant:
        //code
        break;
    default:
        //code
        break;
}
```

You can add as many cases as you want.  And note that "someConstant" must be a constant (final) value.  As far as I know, you cannot use variables for cases.

Comment: For that last point, just pulled up a quick example in Eclipse for funsies. Trying a variable in a `case` gets me the error `case expressions must be constant expressions`. Pretty much what we expected.

Comment: @DennisMeng Mmm.  I edited that around a bit.  I think you can use a variable declared as `final`.